# Is a predecessor subgraph always connected?

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, subgraphs

Given an undirected graph $G$ with non-negative edge weights, how can we prove that the predecessor subgraph $G_{p}$ of $G$ is always connected?

Here's how the predecessor subgraph is defined: for a graph $G = (V, E)$ with source $s$, the **predecessor subgraph** of $G$ is $G_{p} = (V_{p}, E_{p})$, where $V_{p} = \{ v \in V : v.p \neq NIL\} \cup \{s\}$ and $E_{p} = \{ (v.p, v) : v \in V_{p} - \{s\}\}$

I've read that the predecessor subgraph forms a tree, but in the context of that claim, it was assumed the predecessor subgraph is connected and $|E_{p}| = |V_{p}| - 1$.

Can anyone offer a proof that the predecessor subgraph $G_{p}$ of a graph $G$ is always connected (or disprove the claim)?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're dealing with undirected graphs with non-negative edge weights, and you are interested in the predecessors from a single source vertex. Is this correct?

Comment: Also there are multiple ways to define the predecessor subgraph. Do you want a graph in which you add exactly one edge $(p,v)$ for each non-source vertex $v$ such that $p$ is the predecessor of $v$, or you want to have an edge for each possible predecessor? Are the edges undirected or directed towards $v$? If the edges are directed, what do you mean by "connected"?

Comment: In response to your first question: yes, that's correct. For the second, I've updated the question and added the definition of the predecessor subgraph I'm using

Comment: $v.p$ is not defined, but I guess it's the parent of $v$ as set by the breadth first search algorithm.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s$ be your source vertex and let $d(v)$ denote the distance from $s$ to $v$. Let $v_1, \dots, v_n$ be the vertices of your graph in non-decreasing order of distances from $s$.

You can show by induction on $i$ that the subgraph $G_i$ of $G_p$ induced by $\{v_1, \dots v_i\}$ is connected.

The base case is trivial as $G_1$ contains only $v_1=s$.

Consider now $i>1$. It suffices to argue that $G_i$ contains an edge $(v_j, v_i)$ for some $j<i$.
By definition, the predecessor $p(v_i)$ of a vertex $v_i$  (w.r.t. the source $s$) ensures that there is a shortest path from $s$ to $v_i$ that first goes from $s$ to $p(v_i)$ and then traverses the edge $(p(v_i),v)$.
Since edge-weights are non-negative, $d(p(v_i)) < d(v_i)$ which shows that $p(v)=v_j$ for some $j<i$.

Since your graph has exactly $n-1$ edges and it is connected, it is actually a tree.

Comment: Can you explain why it suffices to argue that $G_i$ contains an edge $(v_j, v_i)$ for some $j<i$?

Comment: By induction hypothesis the subgraph $G_{i-1}$ induced by $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{i-1}$ is connected. If there is an edge from any of these vertices $v_j$ to $v_i$ then $G_i$ is connected too. A path from $v_h$ (with $h < i$) to $v_i$ in $G_i$ can be obtained by concatenating a path from $v_h$ to $v_j$ in $G_{i-1}$ (which is connected) with the edge $(v_j, v_i$). A path from $v_i$ to $v_h$ in $G_i$ can be obtained by concatenating the path consisting of the sole edge $(v_i, v_j)$ with a path from $v_j$ to $v_h$ in $G_{i-1}$ (which is connected).